# qtranslate redirecting issue

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I have this strange problem when i created in my wordpress admin a page with 2 languages arabic and english (titles and contents) but when i go to page link this

```
http://site.com/ar/page
```

it redirect me to default language link

```
http://site.com/page
```

I thought the solution the i have to include both titles name in the link so it can work

```
 http://site.com/page_en_title-page_ar_title
```

But it is just an assumption i don't think it's correct

So is there something missing i should have done ??

Answer (score 1):

So **ar** is default language and when you go to http://site.com/ar/page it redirects you to http://site.com/page?

If that is the case, go to **Settings > Languages** and under **Advanced Settings** you have the following option:

- **Hide URL language information for default language**

If selected, deselect that option.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem. Its all about the '/' in the end of the link.

I hardcoded some links in my header.php and this works:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?><?php if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "en") echo     ('/en/cooperation/'); else echo ('/cooperation'); ?>" style="color:#fff;"/>Cooperation</a>
```

This doesnt work:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?><?php if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "en") echo ('/en/cooperation'); else echo ('/cooperation'); ?>" style="color:#fff;"/>Cooperation</a>
```

Notice that the only thing ive changed is the '/' after cooperation in the link URL.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I was wrong using the option "Pre-route" (by default, adds "/es/" before the URL) in Advanced Settings inside qTranslate Options. So, using bloginfo('template_url') every link always took me to the default language...

Now that I just changed to the 3rd option in Avanced Settings, (add in the end ?lang=xx) everything works fine because I can use bloginfo with my subpage adding in the end the current language:

```
href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/mysubpage/?lang=<?php echo qTranslate_GetLanguage(); ?>"
```

Hope this helps!